# How can we pass --max-old-space-size with forever and npm run start

Tags: node.js, npm, forever

Not able to using --max-old-space-size=8192 with forever as we are starting forever by using following command.

forever start -c "npm run start:local" src/server.js

so how we can pass --max-old-space-size=8192 in this.

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I', trying to do  "coverage": "node --max_old_space_size=8192  node_modules/.bin/ng test --code-coverage", and I have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

run on terminal -> `export NODE_OPTIONS=--max_old_space_size=4096`